# MySQL Python incorrect datetime value

Tags: python, mysql, datetime

Hi I'm gathering some info from other website with the time in all formats.
 MySQL datatype is 'DATATIME', I'm getting the following error.

```
OperationalError: (1292, "Incorrect datetime value: 'Tue, 27 Jan 2015 05:59:09 GMT' for column 'date' at row 1")
```

Any help on this is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

To Handle your particular error, do as follows

```
import datetime
your_date = "Tue, 27 Jan 2015 05:59:09"
print datetime.datetime.strptime(your_date, '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S').strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Incase there is a finite set of websites, you need to handle the date formats individually.
Please go through below link.

http://strftime.org/

Comment: how GMT and +0530 is represented in the datetime.strptime() fileds after %a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S.. my date format is Tue, 27 Jan 2015 05:59:09 GMT and Wed, 12 Sep 2012 10:50:34 +0530

Comment: Its showing a ValueError: unconverted data remains:  GMT

Comment: I got the solution for GMT, how can i represent Wed, 12 Sep 2012 10:50:34 +0530 –

Answer (score 2):

I think The Datetime format your passing is different from MySql's ..
The Mysql Dateformat is like `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`